# Azure API Manager - Issue on URL , working even if no sense url and just getting the last segment

Tags: azure-devops, azure-functions

We have found this bug in Api Manager that whenever you pass some similar words in the url its working properly even the url was not correct .

Example:

**working url:** *{{Url}}/regulators*

**bad url but works with the same :** *{{Url}}/../auth/streams/../../regulators*

Anybody encounter the same issue with your APIs?

Please see image below

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Method GET is used to add form data to the URL in name or value pair. If you use GET, the length of URL will remain limited. It helps users to submit the bookmark the result. GET is better for the data which does not require any security or having images or word documents.

Also, this is used only to get the data from address bar in the browser.

We can check with below settings for API Responses:

1. Select the API you created in the [previous step](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/mock-api-responses?tabs=azure-portal).
2. Select + Add Operation.
3. In the Frontend window, enter the following values.
   Display Name(test call) : The name that is displayed in the developer portal.
   URL(HTTP Verb) – GET : Select one of the predefined HTTP verbs.
   URL (/test) : A URL path for API.
   Description: Optional description of the operation, used to provide documentation in the developer portal to the developers using this API.
4. Select the Responses tab, located under the URL, Display name, and Description fields. Enter settings on this tab to define response status codes, content types, examples, and schemas.
5. Select + Add response, and select 200 OK from the list.
6. Under the Representations heading on the right, select + Add representation.
7. Enter application/json into the search box and select the application/json content type.
8. In the Sample text box, enter { "sampleField" : "test" }.
9. Select Save.

Refer to [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-use-azure-monitor) to Monitor published API’s